# How do I programmatically create forum container?

Tags: 7, nodes

I'm trying to programmatically create a forum container in Drupal 7. I found http://www.unibia.com/unibianet/drupal/how-create-drupal-forums-and-containers-programmatically, but it only works for Drupal 6.

What is the equivalent code for Drupal 7?

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! Please report here the relevant code. Questions should never depend from off-site resources, since Stack Exchange aims to have questions helpful to future readers too, even when the off-site resource is not anymore available.